# AppEngie Datastore Join - Getting Child Entity Property thru a Query on the Parent Entity

Tags: google-app-engine

I have Parents with multiple Children Entities. I am interested in doing a query on a Parent Entity and joining the result with one or more properties of a matching child entity. In SQL you would do something like :

```
select p.name, p.phone, c.age from Parent p, Child c 
where p.name = 'some name' and c.name = 'John'
```

Is this possible thru the ancestor-path based query in AppEngine Datatstore.

Thanks and sorry for a pedestrian question (I have browsed thru the Datastore documentation - but wasn't clear if this was possible/not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do JOINs in the App Engine datastore. This is explicitly stated [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview#Comparison_with_Traditional_Databases):

> In particular, the following are not supported: [...]
>
> - Join operations

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I have posted my approach to get around to this restriction. Perhaps it helps others trying to do something similar..

Answer (score 0):

I landed using another approach in Google Appengine's Datatore API, which provides a rather elegant mechanism to implement something like this (or perhaps this is something obvious to the users - so pardon my enthusiasm..). I still can't fetch this thru a single query and requires another fetch - but it seems to be the most efficient (performance and code-quality wise) :

```
class Person (db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  age = Db.IntegerProperty()

class Child (db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  parent = db.RerenceProperty(collection_name="children")

p = new Person (name="Tom", age=21).put()
c = new Child (name="John", parent=p.key()).put() # sets a reference in child to parent

You can now do 

matchingChild = p.children.filter("name=", "John").fetch(1)
```